# topology generated by the closure

Tags: general-topology

I saw the following construction of a topology from a reference book:

Suppose $X$ is a set,let $S\subset X$ ,then the author define the closure of $S$ and  verify the closure $S$ generates a topology $T$.

If the topology is defined as above,what are the open sets in $T$?

Comment: What reference book? Whenever you refer to any other course (a book, a paper, etc.) in your question, you should give a precise reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open sets are the complements of closed sets, of course!

To be more precise: Fix a function $\text{cl}\colon \mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$. For $S\subseteq X$, we call $\text{cl}(S)$ the *closure* of $S$. Then we say that a set $S\subseteq X$ is *closed* if $\text{cl}(S) = S$, and we say a set $U\subseteq X$ is *open* if its complement is closed, i.e. if $\text{cl}(X\setminus U) = X\setminus U$.

The collection of open subsets of $X$, defined in this way, forms a topology on $X$ if and only if the function $\text{cl}$ satisfies the [Kuratowski closure axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms). The author of your book probably verified that the closure operator in question defines a topology by checking these axioms.